# Need help resolving 'Subscript out of range' error when attempting to read strings with leading spaces

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, split, trim

I am automating the exportation of many excel files to PDF. These files are our Room Data Sheets that may have 3-5 tabs for data validation, but only the first and sometimes second tabs are what need to be exported. Rather than hard code the sheet names, I wanted to future proof the macro by allowing a comma-separated list to be used to determine which tabs in a same-formatted set of files (in the event of it being used on something other than room data sheets), or to export the entire file if no list was provided. I have it working for the cell content of "ROOM DATA SHEET,FLOOR PLAN", but in the case of another user typing the list in a more grammatically correct way I began parsing/trimming the list to also accept "ROOM DATA SHEET, FLOOR PLAN". However, my code is giving me the "Subscript out of range" error upon the input of the latter list.

The method for parsing I'm using is to first split the string, then trim the contents of the resulting string array to remove any leading and trailing spaces. While the For i = 0 To... loop doesn't appear to be the issue because of the macro's partial success with the first list, I also attempted switching to the For Each loop to no avail. I've also tried Trim(), VBA.LTrim(), and regex patterns (you can see my regex attempt commented out in the code below).

I also tracked the output of each parse method in cells A9 and A10 to make sure the trim was functioning properly and for both Trim() and VBA.LTrim() the resulting strings had no leading or trailing spaces, as expected. In these cases, the array should have the same strings as the first list according to the output to A9 and A10, but the saving of elements back to the array seems to cause an out of range error for either the array or strings within. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Here is the Sub in question:

```
Sub ProcessFolders(strPath As String, sheetList As String)
    Dim objFileSystem As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim objExcelFile As Object
    Dim objWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim strWorkbookName As String
    Dim sList As Variant

    If Len(sheetList) > 0 Then
        sList = Split(sheetList, ",")

        For i = 0 To UBound(sList)
            sList(i) = VBA.LTrim(sList(i))
        '    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        '    regEx.Pattern = "^\S*\."
        '    sList(i) = regEx.Replace(sList(i), "")
        Next i

    End If

    Range("A9").Value = sList(0)
    Range("A10").Value = sList(1)

    Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFileSystem.GetFolder(strPath)

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        strFileExtension = objFileSystem.GetExtensionName(objFile)
        If LCase(strFileExtension) = "xls" Or LCase(strFileExtension) = "xlsx" Then
            Set objExcelFile = objFile
            Set objWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(objExcelFile.Path)

            strWorkbookName = Left(objWorkbook.Name, (Len(objWorkbook.Name) - Len(strFileExtension)) - 1)
            If sheetList = "" Then
                objWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strPath & strWorkbookName & ".pdf"
            Else
               Sheets(Split(sheetList, ",")).Select
               ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strPath & strWorkbookName & ".pdf"
            End If
            objWorkbook.Close False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps the line "Sheets(Split(sheetList, ",")).Select" is at fault

Comment: It was at fault. I had, at one point, changed that to sList, but I must have undone one too many times and reverted my change down there. Thanks for catching my silly mistake for me, it was driving me mad.

Comment: glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

`Sheets(Split(sheetList, ",")).Select` should have been `Sheets(sList).Select`. I had already made this change so I didn't think to double check this portion of my code. Thank you to Guest for pointing out my error.